# Ignite cluster on EMR

Tags: ignite

did anyone successfully bootstrapped a three-node ignite cluster on EMR without any issues? if so can someone help with step by step process how to resolve.

Thanks
Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed below blog which worked for me.

https://www.gridgain.com/docs/8.7.6/installation-guide/aws/manual-install-on-ec2

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration" >
    <!-- other properties -->
    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide a list of nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>172.31.81.211</value>
                            <value>172.31.82.21</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```